# Meeting is scheduled for tomorrow. Why 'for' here?

Tags: prepositions

1) The meeting is scheduled **for** tomorrow.

2) The meeting is scheduled to be held tomorrow.

I feel 'for' is redundant in this context. I even feel 'for' is used in a wrong way as it literally means the meeting is scheduled for 'tomorrow' as if 'tomorrow' is a person and 'tomorrow' has something to do with the meeting.
I feel the 2nd sentence is a right one.

Comment: Interesting question.  As a native speaker, I hadn't given this issue any thought; it was just how I was used to English working.  But now that you point it out, it is a bit of an unusual use of "for".  It's sort of like saying "put on the schedule for tomorrow", but "for tomorrow" makes it implicit that future days are planned out, with each day having a schedule.

Comment: @PeterC - I don’t know if any usage of _for_ could be considered “unusual” – not when it has [twenty meanings or so](http://www.wordnik.com/words/for).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you don't have a preposition before "yesterday, today, tomorrow," etc., you mean that the verb takes place on that day.

> The meeting is scheduled **for** tomorrow.
>   
> ... So it will be **held tomorrow**.

Now compare that to this sentence:

> The meeting will be **scheduled tomorrow**.
>   
> ... So we don't know yet when it will be **held**. We will **know tomorrow** after it's been scheduled!

Meanwhile, as was said in the comments, "for" is not uncommon when giving the date something is *intended* to take place. (In fact, see @J.R.'s comment below for dictionary mentions of this usage.)

> The party was planned for Thursday.
>
> That pie was supposed to be for Saturday! Why did you eat a slice today?
>
> I set up a picnic with Marion for next Sunday.

Comment: Note, a sentence like "The meeting *will be scheduled* for 2018" is also OK. It means "at the current time, the *intention* is to hold the meeting at some time during 2018, but the exact date has not been fixed." Compare with "The meeting will be scheduled *in* 2018", which means "in 2018, we will decide when the meeting is to be held".

Comment: @alephzero Right. Basically, "for" tells you when the meeting will happen, not when the scheduling will happen. Without "for" (or with another preposition) you know when the scheduling will happen, but not the meeting.

Comment: "That pie was supposed to be for Saturday! Why did you eat a slice today?" Because it's Saturday _today_! Nice pie, by the way. Thanks.

Comment: Not uncommon – and plainly recognized as such by the dictionary. [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/for) says: _used for saying the particular time or date that something is planned to happen :
The meeting was planned for 10 o’clock._ [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for) says: _on the occasion of or at the time of : I've booked a table at the restaurant for nine o’clock._